# Can the Spam filter see repetitive questions?

Tags: discussion, support, spam

This question has been posted 3 times, from what I have seen, this morning:

`https://stackoverflow.com/q/72083199/4961700`

Can the filter recognize repetitive questions and deal with them?

Comment: Another time, please try not to show the actual spam. While we need to be able to discuss such things, we don't want to spread the spam around. If you need to show it, please use a screenshot, not the actual spam text. If possible, even a screenshot should have the contact information redacted, unless that's specifically what you're asking about. I see you actually just posted the URL as a live link, not the title text. Unfortunately for cases like this, the SE system will convert such URLs to display the post title, which is the primary part of the spam for these "Support Number" spam posts.

Comment: @Makyen was about to replace with a screenshot following your comment, but that is no longer possible... Think the 3 originals had more views than this questions though.

Comment: Thanks for trying to do so. I'm sorry the original version of my first comment here was a bit harsh. At the time, I was a bit rushed working around issues in making adjustments to better handle the current influx of spam, destroying the spammer's accounts on SO, reading/responding to this post, and a couple of other things. Even with those things happening simultaneously, my comment should have been worded better. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: @Makyen Cheers, no issue. Will definitely post images next time. Thanks for all you do.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [Charcoal project](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) certainly can. It provides a second layer of protection to Stack Exchange tracking all kinds of spam and it can and does scan for repeated use of numbers even when those numbers are obfuscated.

Charcoal's bots will do their own flagging, but you can use the room to add yours if you like. You can even join in and report problem posts manually if Charcoal doesn't spot them itself.

Comment: I flagged each of those questions anyway.

Comment: @SolarMike Great! Thanks for flagging them. If you see any more, and there will probably be a lot of them (there have been a few thousand so far), please also flag them as spam.

Comment: *Charcoal* is the organisation and *SmokeDetector* is the name of the tool. [Ref.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/25/how-does-spam-protection-work-on-stack-exchange/).